# Transparent Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I am working on a website and I want the navigation (only home the homepage) to be transparent and the image to cover the full screen. This is what I have so far:

[image]

The nav-bar is styled in this way because that's how it is on the other pages.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-trans" id="mainNav">

          <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
            <img class="logo" src="app/assets/images/bunklogo.png" alt="bunk">
            Bunk.
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              Menu
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#tenant">TENANT</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="landlord.html">LANDLORD</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#bunkfaqs">BUNK FAQs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#blog">BLOG</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">TEAM</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#login">LOG IN</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-iten">
                    <button class="btn signup"> SIGN UP</button>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>
  </div>
```

and my css:

```
#mainNav {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #439EE0 0%, #26ADE6 100%);
  /*margin-top: -0.5%;*/
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right {
  color:white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 5rem;
}

.navbar-brand.js-scroll-trigger {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for any custom css hacks here.

To make your Bootstrap navbar transparent, all you need is to **remove the class `bg-light`**.

That's it!

The `bg` in `bg-light` stands for "background". So, if you leave out the class for background color, you automatically have a transparent navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all you need to **separate** the home page from the other pages. To do this just insert an ID on your body section like **#home**.

So, in this scenario you will add the following:

```
body#home #mainNav {
  background:transparent;
  background-image:none;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
}
```

Don't forget that your Slider (or w/e you have after #mainNav), maybe will need some padding-top equals to the #mainNav height, for example (in case that your #mainNav height is 50px):

```
.slider {
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give an extra class to your navbar on your index.html only. (or your homepage html file name.)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-trans navbar--home" id="mainNav">
```

Then you can select this class like :

```
#mainNav.navbar--home{
  background:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use home page body class, for ex.: ".home / .home-index / .index-page" as a parent of ".nav.fixed-top" container.

CSS::

```
.home .nav.fixed-top{
   background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```